# $p$-Sylow in quotient groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Prove that if $P$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ and $N \triangleleft\> G$ then:

1. $ PN/N $ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G/N$
2. $P \cap N $ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $N$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better than writing this out, you better read this excellent [expository paper](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/sylowapp.pdf) by Keith Conrad, **Corollary 6.5** and **Theorem 6.7**.