# $\frac{HS}{H\cap S}$ is a Sylow $p-$subgroup of $\frac{G}{H}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $H\trianglelefteq G$ and $S$ a Sylow $p-$subgroup of $G$, then

1. $H\cap S$ is a Sylow $p-$subgroup of $H$.
2. $\frac{HS}{H\cap S}$ is a Sylow $p-$subgroup of $\frac{G}{H}$.

I already have the proof of the first statement (with the help of this site). I have questions on the second.

Comment: What exactly are your questions on the second?

Comment: For starters, Is $\frac{HS}{H\cap S}$ a subgroup of $\frac{G}{H}$?. How can I show that $\frac{HS}{H\cap S}$ is a maximal $p-$subgroup? Or are the elements of $\frac{HS}{H\cap S}$ even have orders a power of $p$?

Comment: It should be $HS/H$ instead of $HS/(H\cap S)$

Comment: Oh wow, I also totally misread 2. - are you sure you copied the problem correctly? $HS/H$ is a subgroup of $G/H$, which is isomorphic to $S/(S \cap H)$, but $HS/(H \cap S)$ is not meaningful

Comment: As for showing that $HS/H$ is a p-sylow subgroup of $G/H$ (which is both meaningful and true, and what I initially read your question as), are you familiar with the correspondence theorem? The proof of that theorem should give you ideas for this theorem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$p$-Sylow in quotient groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190887/p-sylow-in-quotient-groups)

Comment: You could also do it combinatorially, by showing $S$ is also a p-sylow subgroup of $HS$, and then comparing cardinalities to conclude that $HS/H$ has the right cardinality to be a p-sylow subgroup

Comment: I also have that problem. What I saw on books are $HS/H$. I'm thinking one of my colleague misread it.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor, I think I got it. Thanks.

Comment: Great! Happy to hear it ^_^